# solr boost with multivalued field and specific order key and different weight

Tags: solr

for example i have each document with multivalued field with fixed length

```
popularity: [100, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 10, 80]
```

my plan is using multiple popularity divide by region, `popularity[0]` is global, and `popularity[1...9]` is fixed with `region_id` i store in another database.

why multivalued because the field length maybe increase if region is increase. (maybe 1 each year/3 years)

if i using single value i can boost i.e `boost=log(popularity,2,5)`. But how i can boost if it multivalued ? i.e popularity[0]?

> i'm using solr 6.6 for prod plan to use solr 7.3.1 for next production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't access a specific value in a multivalued field like that.

But you can add a dynamicField and then index the values with their index directly:

```
<dynamicField name="popularity_*" type="int" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

Then you create your document with specific indices for the field names:

```
{
  popularity_0: 100,
  popularity_1: 0, 
  popularity_2: 0, 
  popularity_3: 0, 
  popularity_4: 10, 
  popularity_5: 0, 
  popularity_6: 0, 
  popularity_7: 0, 
  popularity_8: 10, 
  popularity_9: 80
}
```

You then apply the boost by giving the field name:

```
boost=log(popularity_9,2,5)
```

.. and you can use the region_id directly if they're not mapped directly to 1 - 9, i.e. `popularity_abc: 492`.

Comment: is it ok for having many field in document like that? is dynamic field can also using suffix wildcard like that? there's only example for prefix wilrdcard in documentation.

Comment: Yes, and yes. In older versions of Solr the limitation was that sorting by that field would create a sorted list over all the documents in Lucene, regardless of whether they had the field or not. This could become a problem if you had a couple of thousand fields that you sorted by (.. when servers usually had 4 GB of memory), since the memory requirement grew fast. With `docValues` that is no longer the case either, but for a small number (<100) of regions, this shouldn't be an issue anyway.